# Do I need knowledge of fluid mechanics to do the ripple tank experiment?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I have to design and do an experiment for a course of my physics bachelor.
I have thought about ripple tank in order to study diffraction, interference and maybe Doppler effect.

As far as I read from other universities, the theory needed is just the same as for this effects in optics, but I'm not sure if some fluid mechanics are needed because I have not choose this subject so it would be difficult to do this experiment so.

I have asked to my supervisor this question but he does not answer me, so could you tell me which knowledge do I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Huygen's principle does not hold in even (spatial) dimensions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't need fluid mechanics knowledge. Especially, if you're just going to repeat what is shown in this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_tank. You'll just need to show the wave patterns, that's all you need. Also, I would suggest you think more about what experiment you want to make. It is a common mistake of all students to start with a great project and figure out down the road that the project is way too difficult. I would suggest you doing something way simpler than the ripple tank.